# Best way to add a dynamic grid as input in custom extension Adminhtml

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, extensions

I've build a custom store locator extension with it's own grid and edit pages in the Adminhtml and everything works great. For the opening hours of the stores I would like to implement a dynamic grid like for the attribute options.

[image]

Now I've found a solution but I'm hoping there is a better, or at least cleaner way.
What I have so far is adding a renderer to the field in the form `fieldset`

```
class Redkiwi_Rkstorelocator_Block_Adminhtml_Rkstorelocator_Edit_Tab_General extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('rkstorelocator_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('rkstorelocator')->__('Store information')));

        [...]

        $officehours_field = $fieldset->addField('office_hours', 'editor', array(
            'name'      => 'office_hours',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('rkstorelocator')->__('Office hours'),
            'required'  => false,
        ));

        $officehours_block = $this->getLayout()
                                ->createBlock('rkstorelocator/adminhtml_rkstorelocator_edit_renderer_officehours')
                                ->setData(array(
                                    'name'      => 'office_hours',
                                    'label'     => Mage::helper('rkstorelocator')->__('Office hours'),
                                    'required'  => false,
                                ));

        $officehours_field->setRenderer($officehours_block);

        [...]
    }
}
```

And a block class to render

```
class Redkiwi_Rkstorelocator_Block_Adminhtml_Rkstorelocator_Edit_Renderer_Officehours
 extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Abstract 
 implements Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface 
{

    public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element) 
    {
        $required_indicator = $this->getData('required') ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ;

        $html = '
<table id="attribute-options-table" class="dynamic-grid rkstorelocator-officehours" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Day indicator</th>
        <th>Opening hour</th>
        <th>Closing hour</th>
        <th>
            <button id="add_new_option_button" title="Add Option" type="button" class="scalable add"><span><span><span>Add Option</span></span></span></button>
        </th>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

var _form_html_row = \'<tr class="option-row rkstorelocator-officehours-dayrow" id="hour-row-{{id}}"><td><input name="'.$this->getData('name').'[value][option_{{id}}][0]" value="" class="input-text required-option" type="text"></td><td><input name="'.$this->getData('name').'[value][option_{{id}}][2]" value="" class="input-text required-option" type="text"></td><td><input name="'.$this->getData('name').'[value][option_{{id}}][2]" value="" class="input-text required-option" type="text"></td><td class="a-left" id="delete_button_container_option_{{id}}"><input type="hidden" class="delete-flag" name="'.$this->getData('name').'[delete][option_{{id}}]" value=""/><button onclick="$(\\\'hour-row-{{id}}\\\').remove();" title="Delete" type="button" class="scalable delete delete-option"><span><span><span>Delete</span></span></span></button></td></tr>\';

var _rkstorelocator_counter = 0;

$(\'add_new_option_button\').on(\'click\', \'button\', function(){
    $(\'attribute-options-table\').insert(_form_html_row.replace(/\{\{id\}\}/ig, _rkstorelocator_counter));
    _rkstorelocator_counter++;
});

//]]></script>
        ';
        return $html;
    }

}
```

Which gives me the following result
[image]

Now this basically works but getting the current values in there will be quite messy and all in all I'm not too proud of the code I've written (as you might imagine).

I've Googled for several solutions but all generally take this approach. Does anyone know a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Can I have the full code of each file used for this custom module.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It took me way to long to realize that Tier prices looks the way I want. So after looking into how Magento does it with Tier pricing I ended up doing the following.
Sorry in advance for the huge blocks of code but I thought it might be interesting for future reference.

In my form class `Redkiwi_Rkstorelocator_Block_Adminhtml_Rkstorelocator_Edit_Tab_General`

```
class Redkiwi_Rkstorelocator_Block_Adminhtml_Rkstorelocator_Edit_Tab_General extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('rkstorelocator_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('rkstorelocator')->__('Store information')));

        [...]

        $officehours_field = $fieldset->addField('office_hours', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'office_hours',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('rkstorelocator')->__('Office hours'),
            'required'  => false,
        ));

        $office_hours = $form->getElement('office_hours');

        $office_hours->setRenderer(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('rkstorelocator/adminhtml_rkstorelocator_edit_renderer_officehours')
        );


        [...]
    }
}
```

Now for the Office hours block class `Redkiwi_Rkstorelocator_Block_Adminhtml_Rkstorelocator_Edit_Renderer_Officehours`.

```
class Redkiwi_Rkstorelocator_Block_Adminhtml_Rkstorelocator_Edit_Renderer_Officehours
 extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget
 implements Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface
{

    /**
     * Initialize block
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('rkstorelocator/officehours.phtml');
    }

    /**
     * Render HTML
     *
     * @param Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $this->setElement($element);
        return $this->toHtml();
    }

}
```

And the template .phtml file `adminhtml/default/default/template/rkstorelocator/officehours.phtml`

```
<?php 
$_htmlId      = $this->getElement()->getHtmlId();
$_htmlClass   = $this->getElement()->getClass();
$_htmlName    = $this->getElement()->getName();
$_readonly    = $this->getElement()->getReadonly();

$collection = Mage::registry('rkstorelocator_data')
                ->getOpeningHours()
                ->setOrder('sortorder', 'ASC');

$_counter = 0;
?>
<tr>
    <td class="label"><?php echo $this->getElement()->getLabel() ?></td>
    <td colspan="10" class="grid hours">
        <table id="attribute-options-table" class="dynamic-grid rkstorelocator-officehours" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $this->__('Day label') ?></th><th><?php echo $this->__('Opening hour') ?></th><th><?php echo $this->__('Closing hour') ?></th><th><?php echo $this->__('Sortorder') ?></th>
                <th><button id="add_new_option_button" title="Add Option" type="button" class="scalable add"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add Option') ?></span></span></span></button></th>
            </tr>
<?php foreach ($collection as $_item): ?>
<tr class="option-row rkstorelocator-officehours-dayrow" id="hour-row-<?php echo $_counter?>">
    <td><input name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[value][option_<?php echo $_counter ?>][dayindicator]" value="<?php echo $_item->getDayindicator() ?>" class="input-text" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[value][option_<?php echo $_counter ?>][openinghour]" value="<?php echo $_item->getOpeninghour() ?>" class="input-text" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[value][option_<?php echo $_counter ?>][closinghour]" value="<?php echo $_item->getClosinghour() ?>" class="input-text" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[value][option_<?php echo $_counter ?>][sortorder]" value="<?php echo $_item->getSortorder() ?>" class="input-text" type="text"></td>
    <td class="a-left" id="delete_button_container_option_<?php echo $_counter ?>'">
        <input name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[value][option_<?php echo $_counter ?>][id]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" type="hidden">
        <input id="delete-row-<?php echo $_counter ?>" type="hidden" class="delete-flag" name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[delete][option_<?php echo $_counter ?>]" value=""/>
        <button onclick="$('hour-row-<?php echo $_counter ?>').style.display='none'; $('delete-row-<?php echo $_counter ?>').setValue(1);" title="Delete" type="button" class="scalable delete delete-option"><span><span><span>Delete</span></span></span></button>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
        $_counter++;
    endforeach;
?>
</tbody></table>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

var _form_html_row = '<tr class="option-row rkstorelocator-officehours-dayrow" id="hour-row-{{id}}"><td><input name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[value][option_{{id}}][dayindicator]" value="" class="input-text" type="text"></td><td><input name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[value][option_{{id}}][openinghour]" value="" class="input-text" type="text"></td><td><input name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[value][option_{{id}}][closinghour]" value="" class="input-text" type="text"></td><td><input name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[value][option_{{id}}][sortorder]" value="" class="input-text" type="text"></td><td class="a-left" id="delete_button_container_option_{{id}}"><input name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[value][option_{{id}}][id]" value="" type="hidden"><input id="delete-row-{{id}}" type="hidden" class="delete-flag" name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[delete][option_{{id}}]" value=""/><button onclick="$(\'hour-row-{{id}}\').style.display=\'none\'; $(\'delete-row-{{id}}\').setValue(1);" title="Delete" type="button" class="scalable delete delete-option"><span><span><span>Delete</span></span></span></button></td></tr>';

var _rkstorelocator_counter = <?php echo $_counter?>;

$('add_new_option_button').observe('click', function(){
    $('attribute-options-table').insert(_form_html_row.replace(/\{\{id\}\}/ig, _rkstorelocator_counter));
    _rkstorelocator_counter++;
});

//]]></script>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the result:
[image]

Dear future Googlers, By the time you read this Magento 2.x will be released. Let's hope Magento has made this kind of stuff a little bit easier. :)

Comment: How do you store them in DB? As serialized string?

Comment: Nope, I have a second table for the office hours. Seemed better than serializing

Comment: agreed, just need to add the same for products and there will be about 10 name-values pair. So thinking whether store them as serialized strings or create tables with 1 pair per row per product. Thank you for the post anyway!

Comment: The reason I didn't want to use serialized data is because you can't do anything with it while in the database. In the next version of this extension I want to search locations based on opening times. That would be impossible with serialized data. Now I have a collection object that I can use. The extra data caused by the second table was a small trade off

Comment: Saved my day! Thanks for that. I suppose, $this->setTemplate('rkstorelocator/officehours.phtml'); was the trick. Wish there was a better approach to javascript bit.

Answer (score 3):

I give some of my codes written based on Magento templates. Maybe it will be useful.
 
Some tab interface:

```
<?php
class Ssd_Shower_Block_Adminhtml_Shower_Edit_Tab_Options
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{

    /** set own teplate */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('pregnancy/list/options.phtml');
    }

    /** here some implementation of tab interfeys */


    /** options for every row, they will be rendered as dynamic row with inputs */
    public function getOptionValues()
    {
        $period=$this->getData('period');
        $optionsArr = Mage::helper('shower')->getTipList($period);

        $values = array();
        foreach ($optionsArr as $option) {

            $value = array();
            $value['id'] = $option->getId();
            $value['period_id'] = $period->getId();
            $value['tip_content'] = $option->getTip_content();
            $value['sort_order'] = $option->getSort_order();
            $value['update'] = 1;

            $values[] = new Varien_Object($value);
        }

        return $values;
    }

}

?>
```

And pregnancy/list/options.phtml template:

```
<div class="entity-edit" id="manage-options-panel">
    <div class="entry-edit-head">
        <h4 class="icon-head head-edit-form fieldset-legend">Some title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="hor-scroll">
            <table class="dynamic-grid" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                <tr id="grid_head">
                    <th style="width:90%!important"><?php echo Mage::helper('pregnancy')->__('Checklist Items') ?></th>
                    <th class="w-150"><?php echo Mage::helper('pregnancy')->__('Position') ?></th>
                    <th class="w-150">
                        <button id="add_new_option_button" class="scalable add" style="" onclick="" type="button">
                            <span><?php echo Mage::helper('pregnancy')->__('Add Checklist Item') ?></span>
                        </button>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="attribute-options-table">
                </tr>
                <tr class="no-display template" id="row-template">
                    <td><input name="tip[{{id}}][tip_content]"
                               value="{{tip_content}}"
                               class="input-text required-option full"
                               type="text" disabled="disabled"/></td>

                    <td class="a-center"><input class="input-text" type="text" name="tip[{{id}}][sort_order]"
                                                value="{{sort_order}}"/></td>
                    <td class="a-left">
                        <input type="hidden" class="delete-flag" name="tip[{{id}}][delete]" value=""/>
                        <input type="hidden" class="update-flag" name="tip[{{id}}][update]" value="{{update}}"/>
                        <button class="scalable delete delete-option" type="button"><span>Delete</span></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="option-count-check" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var optionDefaultInputType = 'text';
    //template for dynamic row
    var templateText =
            '<tr class="option-row">' +
                    '<td><input name="tip[{{id}}][tip_content]" value="{{tip_content}}" class="input-text required-option full" type="text"/><\/td>' +
                    '<td><input class="input-text" type="text" name="tip[{{id}}][sort_order]" value="{{sort_order}}"/><\/td>' +
                    '<td class="a-left">' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="delete-flag" name="tip[{{id}}][delete]" value="" />' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="update-flag" name="tip[{{id}}][update]" value="{{update}}"/>' +
                    '<button class="scalable delete delete-option" type="button"><span><?=$this->__("Delete")?></span></button>' +
                    '<\/td>' +
                    '<\/tr>';

    var attributeOption = {
        table : $('attribute-options-table'),
        templateSyntax : /(^|.|\r|\n)({{(\w+)}})/,
        templateText : templateText,
        itemCount : 0,
        totalItems : 0,
        //add dynamic row function
        add : function(data) {
            this.template = new Template(this.templateText, this.templateSyntax);
            if (!data.id) {
                data = {};
                data.id = 'option_' + this.itemCount;
            }
            if (!data.intype)
                data.intype = optionDefaultInputType;

            Element.insert(this.table, {before: this.template.evaluate(data)});
            this.bindRemoveButtons();
            this.itemCount++;
            this.totalItems++;
            this.updateItemsCountField();
        },
        //remove dynamic row function
        remove : function(event) {
            if (confirm('<?php echo $this->__("Do you really delete this tip?");?>')) {
                var element = $(Event.findElement(event, 'tr'));
                element.ancestors().each(function(parentItem) {
                    if (parentItem.hasClassName('option-row')) {
                        element = parentItem;
                        throw $break;
                    } else if (parentItem.hasClassName('box')) {
                        throw $break;
                    }
                });

                if (element) {
                    var elementFlags = element.getElementsByClassName('delete-flag');
                    if (elementFlags[0]) {
                        elementFlags[0].value = 1;
                    }

                    element.addClassName('no-display');
                    element.addClassName('template');
                    element.hide();
                    this.totalItems--;
                    this.updateItemsCountField();
                }
            }
        },
        updateItemsCountField: function() {
            if (this.totalItems > 0) {
                $('option-count-check').value = '1';
            } else {
                $('option-count-check').value = '';
            }
        },
        bindRemoveButtons : function() {
            var buttons = $$('.delete-option');
            for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
                if (!$(buttons[i]).binded) {
                    $(buttons[i]).binded = true;
                    Event.observe(buttons[i], 'click', this.remove.bind(this));
                }
            }
        }

    }
    if ($('row-template')) {
        $('row-template').remove();
    }
    attributeOption.bindRemoveButtons();

    if ($('add_new_option_button')) {
        Event.observe('add_new_option_button', 'click', attributeOption.add.bind(attributeOption));
    }
    Validation.addAllThese([
        ['required-option', '<?php echo Mage::helper('pregnancy')->__('Failed') ?>', function(v) {
            return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v);
        }]
    ]);
    Validation.addAllThese([
        ['required-options-count', '<?php echo Mage::helper('pregnancy')->__('Options is required') ?>', function(v) {
            return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v);
        }]
    ]);
<?php
    /** pulling data from Ssd_Shower_Block_Adminhtml_Shower_Edit_Tab_Options **/
    if ($options = $this->getOptionValues()) {
        foreach ($options as $_value): ?>
        attributeOption.add(<?php echo $_value->toJson() ?>);
    <?php endforeach; } ?>
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's somewhat along the lines of how I solved it. There some parts of your phtml that I would like to use :-)